# Crontab running but not scheduling on docker

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, cron

I built a python docker image with a crontab installed. I want to schedule a job. Crontab is running:

```
/etc/init.d/cron status
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

And it's configured:

```
crontab -l
*/30 * * * * root /web/sync_html.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

I even added a just "date" command scheduling for each minute:

```
* * * * * root date >> /var/log/cron.log
```

When I run these commands manually it works. But the scheduling is not working. Any ideas?

**EDIT: Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3

# Copy local files to container
COPY www /web
RUN chmod -R 777 /web

RUN pip3 install -r /web/requirments.txt

# install crontab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

EXPOSE 8081 
CMD [ "python", "/web/app.py", "-p", "8081" ]
```

Comment: Better to show your Dockerfile, is cron process started in `cmd`?

Comment: @Adiii Added :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting `cron` process. change `CMD` to below one but keep in mind it  will start **cron in the background**.

```
CMD ["sh","-c","/etc/init.d/cron start && python /web/app.py -p 8081"]
```

Comment: I tried that and it's not working either, anyway the cron process was up because - /etc/init.d/cron status
[ ok ] cron is running.

Comment: it finally worked when I added newline (\n) to the cron config, toda!